# 1 year contract abroad: what countries can my girlfriend come and work too?

Tags: working-visas

I have a job at a Canadian studio owned by a French company.

My girlfriend and I are both Canadian.

I have the opportunity to work abroad in another one of the parent company's studios for one year. They are based all over the world: France, Japan, Finland, Italy, Singapore, UAE, Germany, Sweden, China, Ukraine, Spain.

I have a bachelors degree, the job is in a highly technical field, but it is an entry-level job in the field.

My girlfriend also holds a bachelors degree.

Is there anywhere where my girlfriend would be able to join me and work?

Comment: Depends on your age, but she might be OK in France under the [France-Canada Youth Mobility Agreement](http://www.ambafrance-ca.org/France-Canada-Youth-Mobility-Agreement)

Comment: Youth Mobility Agreements notwithstanding but why not just try to find work in the same country you have?

Comment: "girlfriend" is not a legal status, "wife" is. In most cases, married/registered/common law partners will be able to come as dependents.

Comment: @littleadv That's presumably why the OP asked this question…

Comment: @zachok could you please clarify if you're interested, or not, in marrying to permit her to join you overseas?

Answer (score 2):

In Finland, [cohabiting partner](http://www.migri.fi/moving_to_finland_to_be_with_a_family_member) is a sufficient status for your girlfriend to get a residence permit, assuming that you would have "Type A" status.

On the other hand, as a practical matter in August 2015, non-Finnish foreigners are not that likely to be hired.

Answer (score 1):

In Japan, since you are not married the fact that she is your girlfriend is irrelevant. In order to come live in Japan with you, she will have to obtain a visa of some sort exactly as if you weren't there.

If you were married, she would be able to obtain a "Dependent" visa provided that your income is deemed sufficient to support the two of you. A Dependent visa does not immediately allow one to work, but one may apply for a work permit which allows one to work part-time up to 28 hours per week. (In order to work more than 28 hours per week, a proper "work visa" is required, and you're back to the previous paragraph.)

**EDIT:** As pointed out in the comments, a working holiday visa may also be an option if your girlfriend qualifies.

Comment: Japan and Canada also have a working holiday visa program: http://www.ca.emb-japan.go.jp/canada_e/Visa/working_holiday.html